# Find the sum of the series with terms given by ${T}_{r}=\frac{r}{(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

The given series has general term as $${T}_{r}=\frac{r}{(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}$$
I have tried to approach this problem by making a telescopic series as follows, but I end up cancelling $r$ in the numerator, $$\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+3)}-\frac{1}{(r+3)(r+4)}=\frac{3}{(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}$$ Please provide an alternate approach to form telescopic series.

Comment: I am really sorry, I am new to the latex coding, hence the problem

Comment: you're not correct-$$\dfrac{1}{(r+1)(r+3)}-\dfrac{1}{(r+3)(r+4)}=\dfrac{r}{3(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}$$

Comment: check this out. https://math-on-quora.surge.sh/#introduction

Comment: http://meikleriggs.org.uk/CUR/

Comment: In India, in JEE exam we are supposed to solve it within 3 minutes, I  don't understand how is it possible?, Simcoe solving for partial fraction consumes time.

Comment: did you read only one comment out of the 3? Besides you get 2.4 minutes to solve each question, ideally. If you had actually read the website, it has the shortcut for partial fraction.

Answer (score 5):

The partial fraction expansion of your summand is

$$-\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{r+1} + \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{r+3} - \frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{r+4}.$$

Then notice that $3/2 = 4/3+1/6$ so you have

$$-\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{r+1} + \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{r+3}+\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{r+3} - \frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{r+4}.$$

And now things telescope like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{r = 1}^{N}{r \over
\pars{r + 1}\pars{r + 3}\pars{r + 4}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 6}\sum_{r = 1}^{N}{1 \over r + 1} +
{1 \over 6}\sum_{r = 1}^{N}{1 \over r + 3} -
{4 \over 3}\sum_{r = 1}^{N}{1 \over r + 4}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 6}\sum_{r = 2}^{N + 1}{1 \over r} +
{3 \over 2}\sum_{r = 4}^{N + 3}{1 \over r} -
{4 \over 3}\sum_{r = 5}^{N + 4}{1 \over r}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
-\,{1 \over 6}\pars{-1} + {3 \over 2}\pars{-1 - {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 3}}
-{4 \over 3}\pars{-1 - {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4}}
\end{align}
Note that $\ds{-1/6 + 3/2 - 4/3 = \color{red}{\large 0}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}{r \over
\pars{r + 1}\pars{r + 3}\pars{r + 4}}} =
{1 \over 6} - {11 \over 4} + {25 \over 9} = \bbx{7 \over 36}
\approx 0.1944
\\ &\ \mbox{}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice answer. By definition $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}=\mathbb{N}$ :)

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use this here $$\frac{3}{2 (r+3)}-\frac{4}{3 (r+4)}-\frac{1}{6 (r+1)}$$

Comment: Can you tell how have you thought of this approach?

Comment: In German Partial Bruch Zerlegung-partial fraction expansion

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner To my knowledge the commonly used term in English is Partial Fraction Decomposition (but, of course, that's nothing compared to the good-old Partialbruchzerlegung!)

Comment: @mrtaurho  Partialbruchzerlegung is far better it looks mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can guess (in general more hope) a decomposition $\frac{r}{(r+1)(r+3)(3+4)} = \frac{a}{r+1}+\frac{b}{r+3} + \frac{c}{r+4}$ for certain $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

So what you have to do is to solve the system given by $ \frac{r}{(r+1)(r+3)(3+4)} = \frac{a}{r+1}+\frac{b}{r+3} + \frac{c}{r+4} = \frac{a(r+3)(r+4) + b(r+1)(r+4) + c(r+1)(r+3)}{(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}$.

Basically you will have to impose that the leading coefficient of $r^{2}$ will be $0$, as well as the costant term, and the one of $r$ equals to $1$.

This traslates into a linear system. If my calculus are correct we get $a(r^{2}+7r+12) + b(r^{2}+5r+4)+ c(r^{2}+4r+3) = r^{2}(a+b+c) + r(7a+5b+4c)+12a+4b+3c$. The system now becomes $\begin{cases}a+b+c = 0 \\ 7a+5b+4c = 1 \\ 12a+4b+3c = 0\end{cases}$. I'm more comfort evaluating the system as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \ 7 & 5 & 4 \ 12 & 4 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a\ b \ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\ 1 \ 0\end{pmatrix}

Since the matrix is invertible (the determinant should be nonzero if I'm not mistaken) it surely exists $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ as required, so you can proceed in solving the system to determine them which will link to other answers given.

Comment: The OP says one is given 3 minutes.  You can speed up the decomposition by plugging in $r=-1$, $r=-3$ and $r=-4$ into your numerators.  This immediately gives $a, b,$ and $c$.

Answer (score -1):

WLOG

$$\dfrac r{(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}=a\left(\dfrac1{r+1}-\dfrac1{r+3}\right)+b\left(\dfrac1{r+3}-\dfrac1{r+4}\right)\  \ \ \  (1)$$

so that
$$f(n)=\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac r{(r+1)(r+3)(r+4)}$$

$$=a\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac1{r+1}-\dfrac1{r+3}\right)+b\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac1{r+3}-\dfrac1{r+4}\right)$$

$$=a\left(\dfrac12-\dfrac14+\dfrac13-\dfrac15+\cdots+?\right)+b\left(\dfrac14-\dfrac1{n+4}\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=a\left(\dfrac12-\dfrac14+\dfrac13-\dfrac15\right)+b\left(\dfrac14\right)$$

Now from $(1),$  $$r=2a(r+4)+b(r+1)=r(2a+b)+8a+b$$

Now compare the coefficients of $r$ and constant to find $$8a+b=0\ \ \ \ (2), 2a+b=1\ \ \ \ (3)$$

Finally solve the two simultaneous solutions to find $a,b$